# AWS Kinesis stream read started after few minutes

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Currently, I am working on my project related to Kinesis Stream.

I have stream with retention period 24 hours and single shard.

I did not send any events to stream yet and stream exist > 24 hours.

When I run my reading threads I wait around 3-5 minutes to read new records.

It looks like request are creating but 0 records processed.

Is it true that stream reads whole stream (last 24 hours)?

Anybody has similar problems?

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample code, especially with how you call `GetShardIterator`.

You seem to be passing in `TRIM_HORIZON` for the ShardIteratorType when when calling `GetShardIterator`. You need to use `AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER ` or `LATEST`. It's well-explained in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#Streams-GetShardIterator-request-ShardIteratorType)

Comment: I implement my Kinesis Client like here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-sdk.html

Moreover, I added loger for getRecords(). My stream alive sine 24 hours. At start I sent to stream 200, 100 and 100 records. Today (after 24 hours) I sent 777 records.
`The problem is during read:
number of readed rec ----- time to read them
0 ----- 0 seconds
0 ----- 1 seconds
200 ----- 3 seconds
100 ----- 5 seconds
777 ----- 44 seconds
So It mean that I read my new records after 44 seconds of reading.